# Shouldn't all things falling into a black hole meet at the horizon?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, free-fall

Consider two observers starting to fall toward a black hole from rest at different distances from the black hole with their worldlines shown on the Kruskal-Szekeres chart below

[image: Two observers falling toward a black hole]

On the diagram, it looks as though they reach the horizon separately, but at the horizon, they are both located at the same point in in space (the Schwarzschild radius) separated by a null geodesic (the dashed line is a null geodesic) such that the proper distance between them is zero.  If they are at the same point in space separated by zero proper distance/time, then aren't they necessarily coincident?  Even if we choose the Schwarzschild radius to be a time (from the perspective of the internal metric), they are still coincident since they are at the same time with zero proper distance/time between them.  If they were separated by a null geodesic but at different locations/times, then they would be separate, but in this case, I don't understand how anything can be said to reach the horizon 'first'.

Comment: “*how anything can be said to reach the horizon 'first'*” - It cannot. See Kevin Brown’s famous Mathpages: https://www.mathpages.com/rr/s7-03/7-03.htm - “One common question is whether a man falling (feet first) through an even horizon of a black hole would see his feet pass through the event horizon below him. As should be apparent from the schematics above, this kind of question is based on a misunderstanding. Everything that falls into a black hole falls in at the same local time, although spatially separated, just as everything in our city is going to enter tomorrow at the same time.”

Comment: On whose clock are both fallers at $r=r_s$ at the same time?

Comment: @safesphere As explained to you many times there is no such concept as " the coordinates of an observer" in GR. The closest thing "the coordinates of a (free falling) observer" are the Fermi normal coordinates of the observer's worldline (i.e. cooridnates of a locally approximate inertial frame travelling with the observer). However, in the Fermi normal coordinates attached to the head, the head crosses the horizon after the feet (this follows immediately from the horizon being a null surface).

Comment: @TimRias Well, my answer to ProfRob has been deleted by the Thought Police from the Ministry of Truth. So please just refer to the above link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General relativity does not have a well defined notion of two different events being at the same location, but at different times. Which points to identify between different timeslices of spacetime is a choice, with different choices being equally valid.

The two events being separated by a null-geodesic means that they are in fact separate events. Moreover, they imply a causal ordering to these events. The event that originates the null geodesic is in the causal past of the event that receives it.

Comment: But in this case, there's no way to establish a causal order.  Both worldlines are at the same position and time at the horizon with zero proper distance between them, so how can one decide which one preceeds the other.  I guess I'm wondering mathematically how one can show that one observer reaches the horizon before the other

Comment: @ChrisLaforet because null geodesics have a well defined direction of time. The event where the object starting from r1 crosses the event horizon lies on the past lightcone of the r2 horizon crossing.

Comment: @TimRias Your answer is misleading and makes incorrect conclusions. See the MathPages link above. The "outward" null geodesic from the object "r1" along the dotted line of the horizon on the diagram physically represents photons "frozen" at the horizon along with r1 itself. The fact that the object "r2" hits these "frozen" photons on its way in does not mean that r1 crosses before r2. They cross at the same local time, but spatially separated, even if from outside they appear crossing at the same point (in part due to the diverging gravitational length contraction at the horizon).

Comment: @safesphere If you jump into a black hole feet first, you will *see* your feet as they cross the horizon exactly at the same moment as your head crosses the horizon. However, if you would jump in headfirst you would not see your feet cross the horizon until your head is well inside the black hole. For small enough black hole your head (now torn apart from your feet by tidal forces) might not even see your feet cross the horizon before it hits the singularity. This asymmetry illustrates the time ordering of these events.

Comment: @TimRias "*if you would jump in headfirst you would not see your feet cross the horizon until your head is well inside the black hole*" - Both cross at the same time, but spatially separated. While already inside, you may see photons emitted by your feet outside, but at the time of this emission your head also was outside. There is no "asymmetry" you are imagining. Here is one way to see this. As observed from outside, your height becomes zero at the horizon due to the gravitational length contraction. What we see as the last Planck length before the horizon looks light years thick to you.